# Redux and ajax request modeling

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there a standard way of modeling ajax request status in store?  For example, say a I have a list of todos, it would be nice if any loaded data in store had a format of 
todo: { status:'loading, data:data  }

I'm just wondering if there are best practices or libraries established around this.

Comment: What you are looking for is a redux middleware. redux-api-middleware comes to mind. I never used it in production but you might find it (or some other similar implementation) useful.